# asp net grid view sort bound fields by text

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting

I am using a asp gridview with BoundFields and TemplatedFields.

```
<asp:GridView ID="RepairGrid" runat="server" CssClass="subitem w100p" 
   AutoGenerateColumns="False"
              OnRowCommand="RepairGrid_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowDataBound="RepairGrid_RowDataBound" 
              AllowSorting="True" OnSorting="SortGrid">
    <RowStyle CssClass="itemRowStyle"/>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="alternatingItemRowStyle"/>
    <HeaderStyle CssClass="headerRowStyle"/>
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="PDF" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                           meta:resourcekey="ColumnPDF" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnExportPDF" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RepairId") %>'
                                 CommandName="ExportPDF" ImageUrl='<%# "~/App_Themes/" + Page.Theme + "/icons/16/icon_pdf.png" %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RepairId" SortExpression="RepairId" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                           meta:resourcekey="ColumnRepairId" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkRepairId" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RepairId") %>' CommandName="Redirect"
                                runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RepairId") %>'/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblRepairId" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RepairId") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ProblemCategory" SortExpression="InternalDescription" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                           meta:resourcekey="repairItemText" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkProblemCategory" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("RepairId") %>' CommandName="Redirect"
                                runat="server"/>
                <asp:Label ID="lblProblemCategory" runat="server"/>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateDate" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="CreateDate" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                        meta:resourcekey="ColumnCreateDate" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="CreateUser" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="CreateUser" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                        meta:resourcekey="ColumnCreateUser" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ChangeDate" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="ChangeDate" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                        meta:resourcekey="ColumnChangeDate" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle"/>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="ChangeUser" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="ChangeUser" ItemStyle-CssClass="itemFieldStyle"
                        meta:resourcekey="ColumnChangeUser" HeaderStyle-CssClass="headerFieldStyle"/>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have managed to sort Boundfields and RepairId Templated Field correctly, but since my TemplatedField ProblemCategory does not have its text in the DataSource and will be filled like this

```
 foreach (RepairDataSet.tms_v_Repair_RepairItemRow row in tblCategories)
 {
    RepairDataSet.tms_RepairItemDataTable repItemTbl = new RepairDataSet.tms_RepairItemDataTable();
    repItemTbl = repairBo.GetRepairItem(row.RepairItemId);
    if (repItemTbl.Count > 0)
    {
       lnkProblemCategory.Text += "<br />" + repItemTbl[0].TextKey;
    }
    else
    {
       lnkProblemCategory.Text += "<br />";
    }
}
```

In the Grid_SelectedIndexChanged I have done special case for sort event args, in witch i define the DataSource, as it should be.

Is there any possibility to sort the TemplatedField by its text and not its value in DB?

Answer (score 0):

Solution one: [Sort Menually](http://geekswithblogs.net/dotNETvinz/archive/2009/07/12/sorting-gridview-manually-with-templatefields.aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonEmpName" runat="server" Text="Employee Name" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Employees">
                </asp:LinkButton>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="LabelEmployee" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Employees") %>'/>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxEmployee" runat="server"/>
            </FooterTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField >
```

Solution 2 [Sort By Columnd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661086/sort-gridview-by-proper-column-which-is-templatefield/7661277#7661277):

```
<asp:TemplateField SortExpression="Status">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkSort" runat="server" Text="Status" CommandName="Sort" CommandArgument="Status" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>

protected void grd_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Sort"))
    {
        FilterExpression = e.CommandArgument.ToString() + " LIKE '%" + txtCaseNumber.Text + "%'";
        BindGridView();
    }
}
```

Solution 3 [Sort with custom templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1597977/gridview-sorting-with-custom-template-fields/9261519#9261519):

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category">
   <ItemTemplate>A value</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Hi, I think your solution 2 is best, but I am not sure what this FilterExpression class should be. Could you explain?

Comment: It is optional, a condition to filter the result from the server side by